# How to display when records were added to already populated MS Access table

Tags: ms-access

Im not sure if this is possible but I have a table in Microsoft Access `table1` already populated with `column1, column2` however I just realized  I need to display when each entry was added to the table, is there a way to add a third `column3` which displays when these records where added

Comment: No, there is not. Always include a date created column with a default value if dates are important to you. I would generally have a date created, created user, date modified, modified user on any relevant table.

Comment: Yes I personally would do the same, I am actually aiding a Pal of mine who did like a days work of duplication and realized a week or so after so I am trying to filter it out by the date created

Comment: Any chance there is a pre- and post- back-up lying around?

Comment: Single back ups which are confirmed then over written daily, Its a small database so what I will do is run a query on the duplications

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Always include a date created column with a default value if dates are important to you. I would generally have a date created, created user, date modified, modified user on any relevant table.

Comment: Yes I personally would do the same, I am actually aiding a Pal of mine who did like a days work of duplication and realized a week or so after so I am trying to filter it out by the date created